# what does ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE stand

Tags: android, android-widget

what does ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE mean. I want to know what does "TYPE" mean in "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE ".
I will be waiting for any kind reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of address it is (home, work etc):

```
Allowed values are:
TYPE_CUSTOM. Put the actual type in LABEL.
TYPE_HOME
TYPE_WORK
TYPE_OTHER
```

See [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.html)

Comment: Also tell me what doed Note in ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note mean. I saw in developer guide,it was given note about contact.what does note mean ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If the user wanted to add any extra information about that contact - such as perhaps to clarify who exactly they were - it would be in a that note

Comment: What is the data type of "ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID ? is it String ? if it is String can we declare as below: public final String contactID=ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID ?
Thank in Advance.

Comment: CONTACT_ID is a long. It is the id of the row in the Contacts table that this data belongs to. You would need to use Long.toString(CONTACT_ID)

Comment: Basically I think ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID  is the column  name in contacts table.
I declared it as public static long iddd = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID; It is showing error as type mismatch. I think it is String.
And also give me link where I can find datatypes of all these types of constants

Comment: The compiler will tell you what the type mismatch is. There are two CONTACT_IDs depending on the data join. You are probably using the string version, but it is still the unique ID of the row. All these constants are in the link I gave you and can be accessed by searching in the developer reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html